# BASH, How do you repeat a command if a user response is No?

Tags: bash

Here is what I am talking about how do I get the script to jump back to the first echo statement if No is selected, Thanks?

```
echo "Please enter some input: " 
read input_variable 
echo "You entered: $input_variable" 

read -r -p "Is this Correct? [y/N] " response 
case $response in 
[yY][eE][sS]|[yY] 
do_something 
;; 
*)
```

{return to first line - echo "Please enter some input: "}

```
;; 
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your prompts in a `while` loop that you only `break` out of once the input is confirmed:

```
while :; do # same as: `while true; do` - keep looping until exited with `break`

  echo "Please enter some input: " 
  read -r input_variable 
  echo "You entered: $input_variable" 

  read -r -p "Is this Correct? [y/N] " response 
  case $response in 
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
      break
    ;; 
  esac

done

do_something
```

Note that not only `N`, but any input other than what is matched by your `case` handler will cause the loop to remain active.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

use a loop around the whole code:

```
quit=0

while [ $quit == 0 ]; do
  echo "Please enter some input: " 
  read input_variable
  echo "You entered: $input_variable" 

  read -r -p "Is this Correct? [y/N] " response
  case $response in
  [yY])
    echo "do_something"
    quit=1
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
  esac
done
```